# visual studio code throws Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec (conda)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am able to run my python from terminal in mac however facing challenges in running the same command from visual studio code terminal

```
(base) sridharkidambi@sridhars-MacBook-Pro learnings % python3  hypothesis.py
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000111e84dc0 (most recent call first):
zsh: abort      python3 hypothesis.py
```

the workspace setting have this value

```
  "python.pythonPath": "/Users/sridharkidambi/anaconda3/bin/",
  "python.condaPath": "/Users/sridharkidambi/anaconda3/",
```

Comment: Are you running virtual environments? Did you activate the environment from the VSCode terminal?

Comment: source /Users/sridharkidambi/anaconda3/bin/activate gets executed when the zh terminal window is opened.